# How to deploy a node application?

Tags: node.js

I am coming from the ancient age of LAMP where I needed a powerful web server to run my PHP code. Nowadays with node, I noticed the server is kind of integrated to node and simply doing `npm run dev` will listen on `8080`.

With Apache I would manage filesystem restrictions, virtual sites, authentication, load balancing, logging, chroot, maximum connections... Moreover Apache is a daemon where node acts as a simple process.

How should I deploy a node (vue.js) website on a server that host multiple sites? I may want to start node as a chrooted service.

Could someone help me to understand how the modern philosophy differ from my vintage LAMP experience?